# xcode bug happen when label update

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, debugging

when i update my label every single image view reset position.
in my app you are can buy food and there is a label that say how many food you have left, but every time I Buy food the label update and the food reset position to where it was in the storyboard.
why is this happening and how to i fix it?

this is the way i update the label text, if it helps:

```
foodStock.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", FoodArray[0][0]];
```

and

```
HungerLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", hunger];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you change the text of your label, the width change!

Comment: But why does all the otter object reset position? and how to i stop this to happen.

Comment: How do I fix this?? it also happen when i change image in a imageView, and then the size don't change

Comment: Try to remove all views and add again.